# How to get a dynamically created timer's tag

Tags: delphi

How to get a dynamically created timer's tag in the function which handles its expiry?

```
procedure TMainForm.TimerExpired(Sender: TObject);
begin
   // how do I get the tag here?
```

And who is `Sender`? The main form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sender is the pointer to your timer object, which invoke this event handler.

So `TTimer(Sender).Tag` will be the tag value of your timer.

Comment: I'd prefer a checked cast, Sender as TTimer, so that any errors at runtime are easily diagnosed.

Comment: Yes checked casts are great, if you don't mind about some (significant in some cases) overheads.

Comment: @Blindfold Even if the `TTimer` instance would fire at 100 Hz, the overhead of an `is` check or `as` cast is minimal.

Comment: Exactly. You are pumping the message queue! For a timer that ticks at no faster than 50Hz. You can do millions of `as` casts in that time. Unless you live in the 1950s.